# Muxing non-synchronised streams to Haali

Tags: directshow, mp4

I have 2 input streams of data that are being passed to a Haali Muxer (mp4 format).

Currently I stream these to Haali directly in a DirectShow graph without a clock. I wondered if I should be trying to write these to the muxer synchronised, or whether it happily accepts a stream of audio data that stops before the video data stream stops. (I have issues with the output file not playing audio after seeking, and I'm not sure why this could occur)

I can't find much in the way of documentation for muxing with the Haali muxer, does anyone know the best place to look for info on this filter?

Comment: You want single MP4 with streams as synchronized tracks? Or separate MP4s?

Comment: @RomanR. single mp4, the 2 streams are 1 video and 1 audio muxed together, At the moment I have no clock (or it appears that way in graphstudionext) and the data is streamed out as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the streams multiplexed into single MP4 file you need single instance of multiplexer (Haali, GDCL, commercial, wrapper over mp4v2 library, over Media Foundation sink etc) with two (or more) input pins on it connected to respective sources, which in turn are going to be written as tracks.

Filter graph clock does not matter. Clock is for presentation, and file writers accept incoming data and write it as soon as possible anyway. It is more accurate to remove the clock, as you seem to already be doing, but having standard clock is not going to be different.

Data is synchronized using time stamps on individual media samples, parts of media streams. Multiplexer builds internal queues for every stream and then consumes data from the streams to build single file, in a sort of way that original stream data is interleaved. If one stream supplies too much data, that is, if data is available too early while another stream supplies data slowly, multiplexer blocks further data reception on this particular stream by not returning from respective processing call (`IPin::Receive`) expecting that during this wait the slow stream provides additional input. Eventually, what multiplexer looks at when matching data from different streams is data time stamps.

To obtain synchronized data in resulting MP4 file you, thus, need to make sure the payload data is properly time stamped. Multiplexer will take care of the rest.

This also includes that the time stamps should be monotonously increasing within a stream, and key frames/splice points are respectively indicated. Otherwise some multiplexers might issue a failure immediately, other would produce the output file but it might have playback issues (esp. seeking).

Comment: cheers - this is what I am seeing, my data is properly timestamped and is delivered interleaved to the muxer, but eventually my audio stream stops but my video stream continues (as there are more video samples for a given duration than audio). I shall look at my timestamps, thanks.

Comment: if audio stops suddenly (freezes without indication of end of stream), multiplexer is expected to keep accepting video up to time of latest audio and then further to fill internal queue. Then video leg is blocked until new audio comes in, data or end of stream notification. Then video might accept additional input and so on. It is actually implementation specific and there is no strict rule that multiplexer has to do exactly this, but it's typical and rational thing for it to do.

Comment: If you still have playable (at least somehow) audio file on the output, you can review what frames/media samples are inside and it should also shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: VLCs debug output shows invalid timestamps (eg *core error: Could not convert timestamp 264066501834*) after seeking, so I guess that is the problem. (we do save clips starting at timestamp 0 rather than an absolute time value), though WMP plays it fine with seeking, VLC can show frozen audio or frozen video.

Comment: Different players play differently because some treat video as master stream, other take audio etc. With a good file there might be no difference but once you play an anomaly it comes up with different symptoms on different players. I can suggest my tool http://alax.info/blog/1605 to trace video and audio data and possibly see what's wrong there.

Comment: Mr R, you're a gentleman and a scholar. Turns out I was resetting my buffer, so when it was exhausted, rather than continue from the end when new samples were added, I resumed streaming from the beginning, resetting the timestamps back to 0. So its no wonder the player got confused after seeking, or me as the problem was of an random nature, sometimes the audio buffer would be exhausted, but occasionally the video.